# How to update the browser's query string with nested properties in a Livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Here is an example of my component:

```php
class ProductCatalogue extends Component
{
    public array $filters = [
        'search' => '',
        'product-category' => '',
        'product-type' => '',
        'product-composition' => '',
        'product-size' => '',
        'min-price' => null,
        'max-price' => null,
    ];

    protected $queryString = ['filters'];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product-catalogue', [
            'products' => Product::query()
                ->when($this->filters['product-category'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['product-type'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['product-composition'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['product-size'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['min-price'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['max-price'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->when($this->filters['search'], function ($query) { ... }
                ->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }
}
```

This works but then the query parameters are:

`?filters%5Bsearch%5D=&filters%5Bproduct-category%5D=&filters%5Bproduct-type%5D=&filters%5Bproduct-composition%5D=&filters%5Bproduct-size%5D=&filters%5Bmin-price%5D=&filters%5Bmax-price%5D=`

How can the `$queryString` property be set to output the following query parameters:

`?search=&product-category=&product-type=&product-composition=&product-size=&min-price=&max-price`

I've tried setting the `$queryString` property to:

```
protected $queryString = [
    'filters.search' => ['except' => ''],
    'filters.product-category' => ['except' => ''],
    'filters.product-type' => ['except' => ''],
    'filters.product-composition' => ['except' => ''],
    'filters.product-type' => ['except' => ''],
    'filters.min-price' => ['except' => null],
    'filters.max-price' => ['except' => null],
];
```

But that throws the following PropertyNotFoundException:
`Property [$filters.search] not found on component`

Is it possible to do this or must each property be defined separately i.e. `public string $search;` etc.?

Comment: PW_Parsons, did you found a solution for this? I run also into this issue; played around with different options but no success so far.

Answer (score 3):

the best solution I found was:

```
protected $queryString = [
    'filters' => ['except' => [
        'search' => '',
        'product-category' => '',
        'product-composition' => '',
        'product-type' => '',
        'min-price' => '',
        'max-price' => '',
    ]],
];
```

This results in having a clean `queryString` as long as non of the nested properties is set. The other way around seams to be not supported (yet) or I simply didn't figured out how to do it.

Ther're a couple of discussions on GitHub around this topic.

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/2036

https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1909

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I suggest to stick with creating individual variables. Use `camelCase`

e.g.

```
public $search = '';
public $productCategory = '';
public $productType = '';
public $productComposition = '';
public $productSize = '';
public $minPrice = null;
public $maxPrice = null;


protected $queryString = [
    'search' => ['except' => ''],
    'productCategory' => ['except' => ''],
    'productType' => ['except' => ''],
    'productComposition' => ['except' => ''],
    'productSize' => ['except' => ''],
    'minPrice' => ['except' => null],
    'maxPrice' => ['except' => null],
];
```

This will give you expected result.